# how to exclude a column from displaying in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, join, oracle-sqldeveloper, syntax-highlighting

I have three tables. I want to select columns from two of them to display but in **WHERE** clause I want to use the third table as well e.g.

```
SELECT table1.colTABLE1, table2.colTABLE2, 
FROM table1, table2 
WHERE table3.colTABLE3 > 10000;
```

It means I want to view the columns of two tables **based on the condition** applied on the column of the third table.

Now the problem is, if I do not write the table3 in FROM clause, it gives me error of "invalid identifier". If I write table3 in FROM clause, it gives warning that you have not used this table (But I used the table3 in WHERE clause).
Please help me in this. I am really confused. How can I display them properly with no error or warning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The warning only appears in the SQL Developer worksheet, if you hover over the `table3` table name, which is underlined to indicate a *possible* problem. It doesn't affect the query execution, and you can just ignore it. (It also says that the table "is not used in the select clause", which is true; not that it isn't used at all.)

If you really don't want to see the warning then you can turn off the ['Semantic Analysis Info Tips' feature](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/sql-developer/21.4/rptug/sql-developer-concepts-usage.html#GUID-D8E22EB9-45F1-4E53-821B-8A5ED7B64B93); from tools->Preferences->Code Editor->Completion Insight, *untick* the 'Enable Semantic Analysis Info Tip' checkbox and click OK.

(In SQL Developer 22.2 at least, the squiggle won't disappear immediately; but if you change and revert the table name then it won't reappear.)

But that will remove all of those tips, not just this specific warning.

You can also go to Tools->Preferences->Code Editor->PL/SQL Syntax Colors, find 'Disconnected Join Graph' (obviously!?) in the list, and untick 'Enable Highlight'. That will stop the yellow squiggle appearing under the table name, for this and other similar warnings; but the tooltip will still appear if you hover over the table name. You just won't have the visual cue that there is a message to look for.

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked like I wanted to do. Appreciated.

Comment: I was just trying to create some screenshots to illustrate the answer, and I can't reproduce it in SQL Developer 19.1 - so it might be a bug in later versions; I am seeing it in 22.2. Out of interest, which version of SQL Developer are you using (from Help->About)?

Answer (score 1):

There is no warning from Oracle if you use a table in the `FROM` clause and none of its columns appears in the `SELECT` clause. That must be caused by whatever client tool you are using.

You have to list all tables in the `FROM` clause, but you also have to join them. After all, you don't want all rows from `table1` combined with all rows from `table2` and `table3`.

An example query could look like this:

```
SELECT table1.col1, table1.col2,
       table2.col3, table2.col4
FROM table1
   JOIN table2
      ON table1.a = table2.b
   JOIN table3
      ON table1.x = table3.y
WHERE table3.col > 10000;
```

You will have to figure out what the join conditions are. Often they are defined by a foreign key.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the comment. Actually I am using Oracle SQL developer. It is still giving me warning with this way as well. The warning is: "Table 3 is not used in the select clause"

Comment: It is giving me the correct output. But I want to get rid of this warning. that table 3 is not used in the select clause.

Comment: @Addison: that warning is from the tool "Oracle SQL Developer", not from Postgres. Are you **sure** you are using Postgres? Oracle SQL Developer is only intended for Oracle database, not for Postgres.

Comment: Hi. is there any way to get rid of this warning?

Comment: You didn't show the warning at all. Please edit the question and add the complete warning there.